# Ubuntu GUI error

Tags: software-installation, gui

I am new to Ubuntu and Linux and just starting my journey. I have successfully installed and have the OS booting from a console window. I have tried to download the GUI through `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`, but ran into this error:

```
Unable to locate package ubuntu-desktop
```

Kindly assist with the steps to follow in order to install the GUI.

Comment: The message i got was "Unable to locate packege ubuntu-desktop".

Answer (score 1):

You might need to update your sources first by running:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

It's also possible that your sources.list files isn't set up correctly. You can configure them in the update manager. They are located in the file /etc/apt/sources.list. If you still have problems after running the update please post the contents of the /etc/apt/sources.list file here.

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: Hi Cioby23,I have tried running "sudo apt-get update" and it finishes successfully but when i run the "sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop" i get the same message "unable to locate ubuntu package desktop". How do i locate the source list?

Comment: Run in the terminal the second command from my answer